# How to get widget data using category id or name in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the default category widget of WordPress.
After selecting category and enter title from that widget I have to display post of that category in my custom template.

How can I retrieve custom data like title, category id etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function rh_get_widget_data_for($sidebar_name) {
    global $wp_registered_sidebars, $wp_registered_widgets;
    $output = array();
    $sidebar_id = false;
    foreach ($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar) {
        if ($sidebar['name'] == $sidebar_name) {
            $sidebar_id = $sidebar['id'];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$sidebar_id) {
        return $output;
    }
    $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
    $widget_ids = $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id];
    if (!$widget_ids) {
        return array();
    }
    foreach ($widget_ids as $id) {
        $option_name = $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['callback'][0]->option_name;
        $key = $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['params'][0]['number'];
        $widget_data = get_option($option_name);
        $output[] = (object) $widget_data[$key];
    }
    return $output;
}

//call this function 
rh_get_widget_data_for('Widget Name');
```